# How to load jar to same local repository using maven in different VM system

Tags: maven, repository, virtual-machine, virtualbox, maven-3

I setup VM Windows7 and Ubuntu, and share common folder named "`share`".

- In windows7 system, the share folder map to disk `Z:/share`.
- In Ubuntu system, the share folder map to `/hgfs/share`.

Using maven, I add `setting.xml` to set local repository, how to  keep local repository  coincide about vm win7 and ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Each user account of your two system should have his/her own `settings.xml` (one per OS).

In their respective `settings.xml`, one can add a `localRepository` directive:

```
<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
```

Specify the right path depending on the OS and you are done.

> they use the same `setting.xml` in the share directory.

First, by default, they do not, even if their `HOME` is set to that folder.  (even then, the settings.xml file would in in `HOME/.m2`, not just `HOME`)

So if you need *one* settings.xml, you need to specify it at the mvn command level, typically in a script or an alias

Windows

```
doskey mvn=mvn --global-settings "Z:\share\settings.xml" -Dmaven.repo.local="Z:\share\repo" $*
```

Linux

```
alias mvn='mvn --global-settings "/hgfs/share/settings.xml" -Dmaven.repo.local="/hgfs/share/repo" '
```

That way:

- the `settings.xml` is the same
- the `settings.xml` does not have to specify a path which changes per OS (that path is set at the command-line level)

Comment: I want to specify a path which windows7 and ubuntu could visit together.But the format in windows is z:/share with the driver , while Ubuntu /hgfs/share with the root directory, How?

Comment: @JimGreen It is best to keep the path separate in their own settings.xml

Comment: So how to not seperate the loacal repository in different VM WIN7 and Ubuntu ? Especially，they use the same setting.xml in the share directory.

Comment: In each OS you have a defined home directory there you can put into `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` which is defined for each OS...that should solve the problem..

Comment: @JimGreen I have edited my answer to propose a way to keep one common `settings.xml`